# How can I get book_id value in controller

Tags: cakephp-2.1

File `add.tcp`

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Issue.book_id',array('label'=>false,'class'=>'','type'=>'text','div'=>false,'value'=>$book_id)); ?>
IssuesController.php
function add()
{
if($this->request->data)
{
$data = $this->Issue->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Issue.book_id' => $book_id)));
$this->set('data',$data);
}
```

File `return.ctp`:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('issue',array ('action'=>'add')); ?>
<div class="rows">
    <div class="cols col3">
    BOOK ID
    </div>
    <div class="cols col3">
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Issue.book_id',array('label'=>false,'div'=>false,'error'=>false,'class'=>'c','type'=>'text','size'=>20)); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<?php echo $this->Form->submit('RETURN',array('class'=>'but')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
<?php ?>
```

How can I get book_id value in controller.. Actually what I am passing value from return and I am getting that value in add.ctp but am not getting that issues in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable in controller

```
 $a=$this->request->data('Issue.book_id');
 then use $this->set('bookid',$a);
```

Then you can use this in view

Comment: $data = $this->Issue->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Issue.book_id' => 7))); is working nstead of 7 i want book_id

Comment: VALUE POSTED IN BOOKID how can i get the value there from return.ctp

Comment: $a=$this->request->data('Issue.book_id');

Comment: I would like if you can give me a plus by clicking the up arrow :)

Comment: $b = $this->request->data('Issue.id');  i want the id based on the book_id    $a=$this->request->data('Issue.book_id');

Comment: $out=$this->Fine->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Fine.issue_id' => $b)));  to get the value over here